# Doctrine 2.4+ public properties and symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Update notes for doctrine 2.4 mention that public properties are now allowed for entities:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/2013/09/11/doctrine-2-4-released.html

> Support for proxy objects for entities with public properties.

Currently symfony default created entities have private properties and public methods. I'm manually renaming them to be public - this is important since we don't know the object schema ahead of time, and being able to inspect and set properties directly is huge.

Are there any pitfalls to this? Symfony docs don't mention anything about this, and with one line above from Doctrine 2.4 update notes, i'm assuming that doing

```
$entity->setValue($v)
```

is as good as

```
$entity->value = $v
```

but i couldn't find confirmation or rebuttal for that online.

Comment: The reason Doctrine recommends (not requires) that you make properties non-public is because of lazy loading.  If a property points to another entity that has not yet been loaded the the proxy object intercepts getWhatever() and triggers a query.  As long as this does not cause you problems then public properties are fine.  I personally think having getter/setters on what are essentially data transfer objects to be a waste of effort.

Comment: @jaro1989 Regardless of how easy it is to add useless code, you still should not do it.  Trust me, no one is impressed by quantity.  And of course you can add type hints directly to the property.

Comment: @jaro1989 Perhaps you could update your answer with some of this deeper meaning?  Especially on how Dependency Injection is relevant.

Comment: @Cerad regarding doctrine 2.4 update about public properties supported, does that indicate that they would also work with dynamic loading? (Otherwise, it doesn't sound fully supported)

Comment: @Rudi if by dynamic loading you mean lazy loading then no, public properties will not support lazy loading.  See my first comment.  There is no easy way to override and intercept a public property.

Comment: @jaro1989 Go through your linked answer and see which of the points listed apply to doctrine entities.  Start to see the problem?

Comment: @Cerad, thank you, that's what I was looking for. Looks like getters/setters are needed for full feature set even though public properties are supported.